# Django: two forms in one view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

How would I write a view with a single form to add a new person, and on that same form, be able to add 0 or 1 or 2 or ... 68757857 images of that same person?

Please refer to the code below.

In models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Image(models.Model):
    person =  models.ForeignKey(Person)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

In forms.py:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name']

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['person', 'image']
```

From what I have seen, formsets are used. I have looked at many examples on SO, read the documentation and I am still confused.

I would appreciate it if someone can provide an example of a views.py that fulfils the specification at the beginning of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

In `view.py` firt of all you have to create a new person instance and then use this instance with formset:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Person, Image, fields=('image',))

def my_view(request):
    form = PersonForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_person = form.save()
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=new_person)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('persons:main')
    else:
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'formset': formset, 'form': form})
```

In `my_template.html`:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for frm in formset %}
            {{ frm.as_p }}
        {% endfor %}   
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Comment: In your code, if the PersonForm is not valid, the view will not return a HttpResponse object. It will return None instead. How do I deal with this case?

Comment: @Flux oops, sorry it just mistake with indent. Check updated answer.

Comment: But then, if form.is_valid() returns false, the variable formset may not be defined when you try to render the template.

Comment: @Flux to avoid this you could just add else block.